# Displaying data in a table using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

**Displaying data in a table using bootstrap in Vue js**

I get resources I need to display them in a table using bootstrap . At the moment I have it done in scss like in image

[image]

I'm not a JS or VUE programmer but I have to write something fast

```
 resources: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Surowiec 1',
        monthlyState: {
          january: 120,
          february: 280,
          march: 45,
          april: 40,
          may: 35,
          august: 60,
          september: 65,
          october: 75,
          november: 80,
          december: 20
        }
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Surowiec 2',
        monthlyState: {
          february: 280,
          march: 45,
          april: 40,
          may: 35,
          june: 37,
          july: 40,
          august: 60,
          september: 65,
          october: 75,
          november: 80,
          december: 20
        }
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Surowiec 3',
        monthlyState: {
          january: 120,
          february: 280,
          march: 45,
          april: 40,
          may: 35,
          june: 37,
          july: 40,
          august: 60,
          september: 65,
          october: 75,
          november: 80,
          december: 20
        }
      }],
    }),
```

Now I have only this

```
   <template>
      <div>
        <b-table :fields="fields" :items="resources">
    
        </b-table>
      </div>
    </template>
....
    fields() {
     
    },
```

Comment: Please share a code that you have tried?

Comment: Well, I don't know how I can display this. In my genes I also have the same months (Lipiec, Sierpien) but I don't know how to do it to display the names of the columns( months) and the values magazyn, potrzebne( These are raw materials and their inventory. How many raw materials are there, how many are needed and how much is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center d-block p-2 bg-dark text-white" >
    </div>
    <b-container>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-table :fields="tableFields" :items="tableItems">
            <template v-for="month in Object.keys(MonthEnum)" v-slot:[`cell(${month})`]="data">
              magazyn:  {{data.item[month]}}
            </template>
          </b-table>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>





export default {
      name: "ResourcesList",
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['resources', "productionPlans", 'products']),
        tableItems() {
          return this.resources.map(({name, monthlyState}) => ({
            name, ...monthlyState
          }))
        },
        tableFields() {
          return  ["name", ...Object.keys(MonthEnum)]
        }
      },
    
    
        data: () => ({
        MonthEnum,
      }),
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepare your data for presentation - the best way in this case would be using `computed` values:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      resources: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Surowiec 1',
        monthlyState: {
          january: 120,
          february: 280,
          march: 45,
          april: 40,
          may: 35,
          august: 60,
          september: 65,
          october: 75,
          november: 80,
          december: 20
        }
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Surowiec 2',
        monthlyState: {
          february: 280,
          march: 45,
          april: 40,
          may: 35,
          june: 37,
          july: 40,
          august: 60,
          september: 65,
          october: 75,
          november: 80,
          december: 20
        }
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Surowiec 3',
        monthlyState: {
          january: 120,
          february: 280,
          march: 45,
          april: 40,
          may: 35,
          june: 37,
          july: 40,
          august: 60,
          september: 65,
          october: 75,
          november: 80,
          december: 20
        }
      }],
      tableFields: [
        "name",
        "january",
        "february",
        "march",
        "april",
        "may",
        "june",
        "july",
        "august",
        "september",
        "october",
        "november",
        "december",
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tableItems() {
      return this.resources.map(({
        name,
        monthlyState
      }) => ({
        name,
        ...monthlyState
      }))
    },
  },
  template: `
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <b-table
          :fields="tableFields"
          :items="tableItems"
        />
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
  `
})
```

```html
<!-- Add this to <head> -->

<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```